.net Maui list zebra profiles
I created an Maui app. I need to list all the profiles on my zebra device.
DOes anyone know to doit?
Thanks
So far, I tried this, but i don't get any results. The if instruction is always false
public void zebraprofile_list()
{
    string EXTRA_GET_PROFILES_LIST = "com.symbol.datawedge.api.RESULT_GET_PROFILES_LIST";

    string ACTION_DATAWEDGE_FROM_6_2 = "com.symbol.datawedge.api.ACTION";
    string EXTRA_CREATE_PROFILE = "com.symbol.datawedge.api.CREATE_PROFILE";
    
    var profiles = new List<string>();
    
    global::Android.Content.Intent dwIntent = new global::Android.Content.Intent();
    
    dwIntent.SetAction("com.symbol.datawedge.api.ACTION");
    dwIntent.PutExtra("com.symbol.datawedge.api.GET_PROFILES", false);

    SendDataWedgeIntentWithExtra(ACTION_DATAWEDGE_FROM_6_2, EXTRA_GET_PROFILES_LIST, "");

    if (dwIntent.HasExtra("com.symbol.datawedge.api.RESULT_GET_PROFILES_LIST"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Tem extra");
    }
}

private void SendDataWedgeIntentWithExtra(String action, String extraKey, String extraValue)
{
    global::Android.Content.Intent dwIntent = new global::Android.Content.Intent();

    dwIntent.SetAction(action);
    
    dwIntent.PutExtra(extraKey, extraValue);
    
    _context.SendBroadcast(dwIntent);

}


According to the official document about Get Profiles List, the intent should be:
    global::Android.Content.Intent dwIntent = new global::Android.Content.Intent();
    dwIntent.SetAction("com.symbol.datawedge.api.ACTION");
    dwIntent.putExtra("com.symbol.datawedge.api.GET_PROFILES_LIST", "");
    _context.SendBroadcast(dwIntent);

And receive the list in the BroadcastReceiver:
    [BroadcastReceiver(Exported = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] {"com.symbol.datawedge.api.ACTION"})]
    public class ListReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context? context, Intent? intent)
        {
            //var bundler = intent.Extras;
            if (intent.HasExtra("com.symbol.datawedge.api.RESULT_GET_PROFILES_LIST"))
            {
                var list = intent.GetStringArrayExtra("com.symbol.datawedge.api.RESULT_GET_PROFILES_LIST");
            }
        }
    }

